# wpf datagrid row binding class's property do not work

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I want to bind the datagrid's row with class's property, but it does not work

```
  <DataGrid Name="ProductsGrid" Background="AliceBlue"  Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CanUserAddRows="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="HedgeStyle" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Positions.hedgeStyle}"/>

     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

the datagrid's binding class structure is:

```
 public class NotifiedTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public string ProductName;

    private BopuCtpPositions _Positions;
    public BopuCtpPositions Positions
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Positions;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._Positions)
            {
                this._Positions = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Positions");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

the internal class "Positions" structure:

```
public class BopuCtpPositions
{
    public int hedgeStyle;
}
```

Comment: which property dint work?

Comment: @kylejan - Show you class structure and also have you set DataContext of dataGrid?

Comment: the property Positions.hedgeStyle dint work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BopuCtpPositions should also be inherited by INotifyPropertyChanged. After I did this, it could work properly